# PyTorch: while loading batched data using Dataloader, how to transfer the data to GPU automatically

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

If we use a combination of the `Dataset` and `Dataloader` classes (as shown below), I have to explicitly load the data onto the **GPU** using `.to()` or `.cuda()`. Is there a way to instruct the dataloader to do it automatically/implicitly?

Code to understand/reproduce the scenario:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np

class DemoData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, limit):
        super(DemoData, self).__init__()
        self.data = np.arange(limit)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return (self.data[idx], self.data[idx]*100)

demo = DemoData(100)

loader = DataLoader(demo, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)

for i, (i1, i2) in enumerate(loader):
    print('Batch Index: {}'.format(i))
    print('Shape of data item 1: {}; shape of data item 2: {}'.format(i1.shape, i2.shape))
    # i1, i2 = i1.to('cuda:0'), i2.to('cuda:0')
    print('Device of data item 1: {}; device of data item 2: {}\n'.format(i1.device, i2.device))
```

Which will output the following; note - without explicit device transfer instruction, the data is loaded onto **CPU**:

```bash
Batch Index: 0
Shape of data item 1: torch.Size([50]); shape of data item 2: torch.Size([50])
Device of data item 1: cpu; device of data item 2: cpu

Batch Index: 1
Shape of data item 1: torch.Size([50]); shape of data item 2: torch.Size([50])
Device of data item 1: cpu; device of data item 2: cpu
```

A possible solution is at [this PyTorch GitHub repo. Issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/11372#issuecomment-589981738)(*still open at the time this question was posted*), but, I am unable to make it to work when the dataloader has to return multiple data-items!

Comment: No-one has come across this problem?

Comment: The `collate-fn` parameter is not useful when the dataset returns tuple of values in each batch. So still looking for better workarounds!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can modify the `collate_fn` to handle several items at once:

```py
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import default_collate

device = torch.device('cuda:0')  # or whatever device/cpu you like

# the new collate function is quite generic
loader = DataLoader(demo, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, 
                    collate_fn=lambda x: tuple(x_.to(device) for x_ in default_collate(x)))
```

Note that if you want to have multiple workers for the dataloader, you'll need to add

```py
torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

after your `if __name__ == '__main__'` (see [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/40403#issuecomment-649868816)).

Having said that, it seems like using `pin_memory=True` in your `DataLoader` would be much more efficient. Have you tried this option?
See [memory pinning](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#memory-pinning) for more information.

---

**Update (Feb 8th, 2021)**
This post made me look at my "data-to-model" time spent during training.
I compared three alternatives:

1. `DataLoader` works on CPU and only after the batch is retrieved data is moved to GPU.
2. Same as (1) but with `pin_memory=True` in `DataLoader`.
3. The proposed method of using `collate_fn` to move data to GPU.

From my limited experimentation it seems like the second option performs best (but not by a big margin).
The third option required fussing about the `start_method` of the data loader processes, and it seems to incur an overhead at the beginning of each epoch.

Comment: the `spawn` instruction didn't work for me, is it specific to particular version?

Comment: @anurag I don't know.